# Whats the difference between default and inverse? (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing the one month rails class and in one of the lessons we're told to change some stuff from default to inverse. He doesn't go over why or whats the significance of it. If someone could explain to me that would be awesome.

Heres an example: nav `class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"` vs nav `class="navbar navbar-default role="navigation"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not about a general programming problem and has a answer that will most likely not be helpful to future browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Styling classes (CSS) are responsible for configuring the visual look and feel of the elements.

Changing `navbar-default` to `navbar-inverse` simply changes the look of the navigation bar from bright to dark color palette.

You can check it out here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-inverted

Comment: You beat me by a second! +1

Comment: @abtrout I thought it was other way around :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just CSS styling. `.navbar-inverse` inverts the background/foreground/border colors.

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

FYI, the [bootstrap components](http://getbootstrap.com/components) page spells out most (if not all) of what bootstrap has to offer. It's a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the nav bar is inverse. The default is in almost white, while the inverse is in a darker shade.

[example of inverse at the bottom of the page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

it does the same trick just different shade of color. Default will always be white while -inverse changes the background color to dark (like changing to dark mode on iphone).