# React-Bootstrap tags and attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on Bootstrap home project, and in general, I'm new to bootstrap, on boilerplate code I found a tag with inverse attribute not class and couple of others, I've been through documentation and I haven't found this inverse fixed attributes anywhere?

```
 <Navbar inverse fixedTop fluid collapseOnSelect>
```

Answer (score 1):

The inverse fixed is not available, you can check

```
 <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
```

You can find out here https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/.

Comment: Its not the same package this is react-strap and iam using react-bootstrap. The real question is what are this inver fixedTop properties, how are they called and where can i find full list of them and how to use them? beacuse in documentation there is not word of it. Is it part of bootstrap 4 or just this react libary from npm?

Answer (score 0):

`inverse` appears to have been deprecated around version 4.0. It's in [legacy versions of the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) and [old questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016657/whats-the-difference-between-default-and-inverse-bootstrap/23016919). There's no mention of it in the [current NavBar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/).

`fixed-top` has [new syntax](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/):

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, but its not class its some kind of prop thats what I'm intrested abotu how to use it to my advantage and why is it not in docs?

Comment: If it's not in the docs, it's likely unsupported, or from a previous version. What is the source of your boilerplate code?